# $E/F$ is a normal extension iff $E$ is a splitting field for some polynomial $f\in F[X]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

> $E/F$ is  a finite extension. Prove that $E/F$  is a normal extension $\iff$ $E$ is a splitting field for some polynomial $f\in F[X]$.

*An extension $E/F$ is called normal if it is algebraic and if $\alpha \in E$ then minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ splits in $E$*.

**My try**:

Let $\{a_1,a_2,...a_n\}$ be a basis of $E/F$. Let $f_i$ be the minimal polynomial of $a_i$ over $F$. Then $f_i$ splits in $E$. Consider $f=f_1f_2\cdots f_n$. Then $f$ splits in $E$. Since $a_i$ are the roots of $f$ then $E$ is the splitting field of $E$ over $F$.

Conversely, let $\alpha \in E$ and $g$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha $ over $F$. To show that $g$ splits in $E$

How to show this? Any help

Comment: I don’t see normality coming into your argument. And while we’re at it, you’d better tell us your definition of normality (there are several).

Comment: @Lubin;I have provided it ;Please help now

Comment: @learnmore: Apologies for the off-topic comment, but I just wanted to point out that you seem to be in the habit of putting space before, and not after, punctuation. This is incorrect English orthography. For example, `We are walking. They are smiling.` is correct, whereas `We are walking .They are smiling .` is incorrect.

Comment: Will look after that in near future. Well for the time being can you help me out to complete this proof@ZevChonoles

Comment: Sorry, but the only help I could give passes through another (fairly easily provably equivalent) definition of normality, namely that $E$ is normal over $F$ if every $F$-homomorphism of $E$ into an algebraically closed field containing $E$ sends $E$ into (and thus onto) itself.